# Cannot call a method on a null-valued expression

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I have a script that looks in a directory for *.bak files and moves the files to a backup directory renaming the destination directory based on a date.

In 1 environment everything works as a expected, in another it fails with 'cannot call a method on a null-valued expression' when just setting the variables.  The exact same version of PS 4.0 is running in both environments.

```
$SourceDir = "D:\APPS\Logs"
$DestinationDir = "D:\APPS\ServerLog_Archives\"
$files = get-childitem -path $SourceDir -Filter *.bak
$Directory = $DestinationDir + "" + $file.CreationTime.Date.ToString('yyyy') + "\" + $file.CreationTime.Date.ToString('dd-MMM')
```

If there are .bak files present `$files` returns the following, otherwise the variable returns NULL.

```
    Directory: D:\APPS\Logs


Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name                                                                                                                                   
----                -------------     ------ ----                                                                                                                                   
-a---        2017-08-25   6:38 PM     100068 jfserver5.bak                                                                                                                          
-a---        2017-08-25   6:38 PM     100068 jfserver6.bak
```

In 1 environment `$Directory` returns the destination directory whether or not `$files` was NULL or returned something.

```
D:\APPS\ServerLog_Archives\2017\20-Nov
```

In the other environment I get the error:

```
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:6 char:1
+ $Directory = $DestinationDir + "" + $file.CreationTime.Date.ToString('yyyy') + " ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

Why would this work in 1 environment and not another running the same version of PS?  Perhaps there is a better way to doing this, any suggestions will be much appreciated.

Comment: Your variable `$file` is undefined. Where do you expect it to come from?

Comment: I'm guessing that you've not included all of your code above and you're using a `foreach ($file in $files)` somewhere we don't know?

Comment: Yes, I have a for each after this.  I was just showing the variables since it was breaking at that point.  I just ran this again in the 'working' environment and I am now getting the same error.  I guess a variable was still held in memory or something...   I'll go back and work on this some more.  I'm open to any nudges in the right direction.

Comment: Loop variables of `foreach` loops should be used *inside* the loop. Not *before* the loop.